# Where to store constants for layout in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was just wondering how constants are dealt with when needed? Is the code behind just used to store them in the resource dictionary?

How are settings and preferences typically stored when coding in wpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare them in xaml as well, like this (if something like this is what you are thinking of):

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <system:String x:Key="myConstant">600</system:String>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And then use it as a `StaticResource`, e.g. `{StaticResource myConstant}`